# Remove Cloud Cover with Python Earth Engine API

Tags: python, google-earth-engine, google-earth, cloud-cover

I am attempting to use google's cloudscore methodology to remove clouds from LANDSAT8 imagery.  I am using python to do this.  I can get this to work in java from the web code editor, but am unable to get the same results from the python API.

**Java**

```
var LC8_BANDS = ['B2',   'B3',    'B4',  'B5',  'B6',    'B7',    'B10'];
var STD_NAMES = ['blue', 'green', 'red', 'nir', 'swir1', 'swir2', 'temp'];

// Compute a cloud score.  This expects the input image to have the common
// band names: ["red", "blue", etc], so it can work across sensors.
var cloudScore = function(img) {
  // A helper to apply an expression and linearly rescale the output.
  var rescale = function(img, exp, thresholds) {
    return img.expression(exp, {img: img})
        .subtract(thresholds[0]).divide(thresholds[1] - thresholds[0]);
  };

  // Compute several indicators of cloudyness and take the minimum of them.
  var score = ee.Image(1.0);
  // Clouds are reasonably bright in the blue band.
  score = score.min(rescale(img, 'img.blue', [0.1, 0.3]));

  // Clouds are reasonably bright in all visible bands.
  score = score.min(rescale(img, 'img.red + img.green + img.blue', [0.2, 0.8]));

  // Clouds are reasonably bright in all infrared bands.
  score = score.min(
      rescale(img, 'img.nir + img.swir1 + img.swir2', [0.3, 0.8]));

  // Clouds are reasonably cool in temperature.
  score = score.min(rescale(img, 'img.temp', [300, 290]));

  // However, clouds are not snow.
  var ndsi = img.normalizedDifference(['green', 'swir1']);
  return score.min(rescale(ndsi, 'img', [0.8, 0.6]));
};

var image = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1')
.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(2018,2018,'year'))
.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(03,05,'month'))
.map(function(img) {
  // Invert the cloudscore so 1 is least cloudy, and rename the band.
  var score = cloudScore(img.select(LC8_BANDS, STD_NAMES));
  score = ee.Image(1).subtract(score).select([0], ['cloudscore']);
  return img.addBands(score);
});


var image = image.qualityMosaic('cloudscore')


var fc = ee.FeatureCollection('users/hoogstra_5/TN_CensusTractBoundaries')
var image = image.clip(fc.filterMetadata("Name","equals","kml_61239"))

var vizParams = {'bands': ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], 'max': 30000, 'gamma': 1.6};

Map.addLayer(image, vizParams);
```

**PYTHON**

```
LC8_BANDS = ['B2',   'B3',    'B4',  'B5',  'B6',    'B7',    'B10'];
STD_NAMES = ['blue', 'green', 'red', 'nir', 'swir1', 'swir2', 'temp'];

def cloudscore(img):

    def rescale(img1, exp, thresholds):
        return img1.expression(exp, {img1: img1}).subtract(thresholds[0]).divide(thresholds[1] - thresholds[0])

    score = ee.Image(1.0);

    score = score.min(rescale(img, 'img.blue', [0.1, 0.3]));

    score = score.min(rescale(img, 'img.red + img.green + img.blue', [0.2, 0.8]));

    score = score.min(rescale(img, 'img.nir + img.swir1 + img.swir2', [0.3, 0.8]));

    score = score.min(rescale(img, 'img.temp', [300, 290]));

    ndsi = img.normalizedDifference(['green', 'swir1']);

    return score.min(rescale(ndsi, 'img', [0.8, 0.6]));

def badSelect(img):
    # Invert the cloudscore so 1 is least cloudy, and rename the band.
    score = cloudscore(img.select(LC8_BANDS, STD_NAMES))
    score = ee.Image(1).subtract(score).select([0], ['cloudscore'])
    return img.addBands(score)

image = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1')\
        .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(2018,2018,'year'))\
        .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(3,3,'month'))\
        .map(badSelect)

image = image.qualityMosaic('cloudscore')

image_out = image.clip(fc.filterMetadata("Name","equals",kml))

vizParams = {'bands': ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], 'max': 30000, 'gamma': 1.6}

Coordinate_List = fc.filterMetadata("Name","equals",kml).geometry().bounds().getInfo()['coordinates']

geo = ee.Geometry.Polygon(Coordinate_List)

task = ee.batch.Export.image.toDrive(  
                    image = image_out.visualize(vizParams),
                    description = FileName,
                    folder = folderName,
                    scale=30,
                    region=Coordinate_List,
                    fileFormat='GeoTIFF'
                    )

task.start()
```

I am recieving the error: "keys must be str, int, float, bool or None, not Image" from my error handling module but am having a hard time troubleshooting where.  I believe it to be the function passing image objects and expecting keys.

Answer (score 2):

In your **rescale** function

```
def rescale(img1, exp, thresholds):
        return img1.expression(exp, {img1: img1}).subtract(thresholds[0]).divide(thresholds[1] - thresholds[0])
```

You have i'd say two mistakes, as the second argument for expression you have **{img1:img1}**
which should be **{'img':img1}**. 1 because python expects a string as a key while js automatically reads keys as strings or numbers. This is where your error message "keys must be str, int, float, bool or None, not Image" comes from. 2 because in your expressions you have img as img.red, img.blue etc and not img1.red, img1.blue etc. So it should be

```
def rescale(img1, exp, thresholds):
        return img1.expression(exp, {"img": img1}).subtract(thresholds[0]).divide(thresholds[1] - thresholds[0])
```